# Losing session state in shared configuration IIS

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

Our configuration is like this:

- Two web app servers in NLB cluster with shared IIS configuration
- Two DB servers in DB cluster
- Session is stored in database

When we test our clusters, if we shut down one app server and one DB server, user session is not preserved and user is redirected to the login page.

If we shut down only one DB server, session is preserved.
Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this behaviour?
Could it be something related to the IIS shared configuration?

Comment: What's the affinity on your NLB cluster?  Have you synchronized the machine key? (If I remember correctly that was set in the machine.config which wouldn't be synchronized with "shared iis config".

Comment: I have to check for affinity and let you know. I presumed that in shared IIS config, machine.config would also be shared, but I might be wrong. I will check machine key also and if it's not the same on both nodes, I will adjust that and come up with results here. Thanks for your comment, it might set me in good direction.

Comment: Affinity is set to "Single" and machine keys are not the same. We will sync machine keys and check the outcome.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?